# Why is my Express server code returning a object when run outside of systemd but nothing is returned when running in systemd?

Tags: express, response, systemd

When I run a curl script and my express server code is running outside of systemd, a record is created in my database table and a json "user" object is returned to stdout. When my express server code is running in systemd, the curl script creates a record in my database table. However, the "user" object is not returned to stdout and the curl script appears to hang. I have to ctrl-c to terminate it. Why am I not seeing a user object in stdout when systemd is involved?

Here is my curl script.

```
curl -v  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userName":"bill", "password":"your_password", "email" : "bill@gmail.com"}' http://some-server:8080/api/users/signup
```

Here is my server code. The code that sends the user object in a response is (see below): `return res.status(201).send(user);`

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const db = require("./index.js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = db.users;

// Signing a user up. Hash user password before
// its saved to the database with bcrypt.
const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userName, email, password } = req.body;
        const data = {
            userName,
            email,
            password: await bcrypt.hash(password, 10),
        };
        // Save user in the database
        const user = await User.create(data);

        // If a user's details are captured generate a token
        // with the user's id and the SECRET_KEY in the env
        // file set cookie with the token generated
        if (user) {
            let token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                expiresIn: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            });

            // Send user's details
            return res.status(201).send(user);
        } else {
            return res.status(409).send({"error" : "Your account could not be created with the information you supplied."});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};


module.exports = {
    signup
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I had process.env.SECRET_KEY stored in a .env file which systemd doesn't read. Fixed by adding the key to a systemd unit file.